# Django - Change URL displayed in browser

Tags: python, django

I am making a simple code editor. Each user is allocated a six character long id which needs to be appended to the URL. So, if some accesses the page on `localhost:8000/myapp/`, the URL needs to change to `localhost:8000/myapp/<token>`.

I am using the following function to generate that token key -

```
def id_generator(self,size=6, chars=string.ascii_lowercase + string.digits):
        return ''.join(random.choice(chars) for _ in range(size))
```

I have created a middleware but I am confused how to proceed further. What should I use - process_request() or process_response()?

And how show I define either of them, so that URL changes but functionality remains the same.

Answer (score 1):

If I am right :

Write a view for `localhost:8000/myapp/` In this view generate your token and then redirect it to new url from the view .

```
def mytoken(request):
    token = '0-wedfbdhfgm'

    return redirect(localhost:8000/myapp/token='+token)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a two-step process. You need to create

- a view with a matching url to retrieve your individual token
- a view with a matching named url to provide the result to the user

**urls.py**

```
...

url(r'^myapp/(?P<token>\w+)/$', views.your_user_result_view, name='your-user-result-view'),
url(r'^myapp/$', views.your_token_appender_view, name='your-token-appender-view'),

...
```

**views.py**

```
...

def your_user_result_view(request):
    ...

def your_token_appender_view(request):
    token = ...

    redirect(reverse('your-user-result-view',kwargs={'token':token}))

...
```